# access 2010 complie error: label not defined

Tags: ms-access, vba

receiving error message on this code other ones are working

```
Private Sub Command11FindLastName_Click()

On Error GoTo Err_FindLastName_Click

   Dim Searchstr
   Dim Resp

BeginSearch:

    Searchstr = Left(InputBox("Enter Last Name"), 11)

    Set dbs = CurrentDb

    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("tblRecords", dbOpenDynaset)

    rst.FindFirst ("[Last Name] = " & Searchstr & "")

       If rst.NoMatch Then

            Resp = MsgBox("Last Name " & Searchstr & " not found.  New Search?", vbYesNo)

            If Resp = vbYes Then

                GoTo BeginSearch

            End If

    Else

        Me.Filter = "((tblRecords.[Last Name] = " & Searchstr & "))"

        Me.FilterOn = True

        Me.Refresh

        DoCmd.Close acForm, "MainMenu"

      End If

Exit_FindSSN_Click:

    Exit Sub

Err_FindSSN_Click:

  MsgBox Err.Description

    Resume Exit_FindLastName_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: `On Error GoTo Err_FindLastName_Click` fails when there is not a label line which matches ...  ie `Err_FindLastName_Click:` ... your code does not include that label.  Make sense?

Comment: the error is on this line Resume Exit_FindLastName_Click

Comment: OK ... it's basically the same issue.  There is no `Exit_FindLastName_Click:` label to `Resume` at.  There is a `Exit_FindSSN_Click:` label, but no `Exit_FindLastName_Click:` label.  Do you see what I mean?  *"Label not defined"* tells you what the problem is.

Comment: I also suggest you add an 'Option Explicit' at the top of your code and compile it. You have a second problem too...It appears you copied and pasted this code from another subroutine, then changed one of the names but not all...

Comment: I seen where I had missed some of the changes when you sent it back. Corrected the rest and now it works. thank you